# Посчитать содержимое массива

Tags: php

Помогите, не могу решить следующую задачу на выборку из вложенных массивов.

```
      Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [quanty] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [quanty] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [quanty] => 2
        )
)
```

Что бы на выходе было так:

id - 2 = 4 шт

id - 4 = 2 шт

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = array(
    array('id'=>2, 'quanty'=>2),
    array('id'=>4, 'quanty'=>2),
    array('id'=>2, 'quanty'=>2),
);

$sum = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
    if(isset($sum[$input[$i]['id']])) {
        $sum[$input[$i]['id']] += $input[$i]['quanty'];
    } else {
        $sum[$input[$i]['id']] = $input[$i]['quanty'];
    }
}
print_r($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'quantity' => 2
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'quantity' => 2
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'quantity' => 2
    ],
];

$arr2 = [];

array_walk($arr, function ($item) use (&$arr2){
    @$arr2[$item['id']] += $item['quantity'];
});

foreach ($arr2 as $key => $val) {
    echo 'id - ' . $key . ' = ' . $val . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Плохая практика использовать `@`(

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive не совсем так.  В данном случае подовляется Undefined offset при первом обращении к $arr2[$item['id']]. Это Notice, и для этого кейса глушить на уровне массива вполне воможно. Плохая практика использовать @ без мозгов.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
      $data=array(
    "0" => array(
            "id" => "2",
            "quanty" => "2"
        ),

    "1" => array(
            "id" => "2",
            "quanty" => "2"
        ),

    "2" => array(
            "id" => "4",
            "quanty" => "2"
        )
);

      foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $eniq[]=$value["id"];

        $mass[$value["id"]]=$value["quanty"];
      }

      $res=array_count_values ($eniq);
foreach ($mass as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($res as $key2 => $value2) {
                                            if($key1==$key2){
$bin[$key1]=$value1*$value2.'шт';
        }
    }
}
print_r($bin);
?>
```